# How do I identify repeated irreducible factors?

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

[image]

I thought my solution was correct - but it seems like that's not the case. Can anyone possibly explain to me why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $x^2 + 1$ is an irreducible quadratic. On the other hand, using the fact that $x^2 - 1 = (x - 1)(x + 1)$, we can rewrite the expression as

$$(x - 1)^2 (x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2$$

How many linear terms are there now?